# Graph theory-tree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree with exactly two vertices of degree $7$ and exactly $20$ vertices of degree $100$. What is the minimum possible number of vertices in a tree $T$ that satisfies those restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v$ be the number of vertices. We have the number of edges to be $v-1$ and the number of faces to be $1$. From handshake lemma, we have that
$$\sum_{i=1}^v d_i = 2(v-1)$$
We are given that $d_1=d_2=7$, $d_3=d_4=\cdots = d_{22} = 100$. This means we have $$2\cdot 7 + 20\cdot 100 + \sum_{i=23}^v d_i = 2v-2$$
Further, $d_i \geq 1$, which gives us that
$$2014+(v-22) \leq 2v-2 \implies v \geq 1994$$

Further, $v=1994$ is attained as follows. Consider a line with $22$ vertices. The left and right corner vertices are connected to $6$ leaves. The middle $20$ vertices are each connected to $98$ leaves. The total number of vertices then is given by
$$22 + 2\cdot6 + 20\cdot98 = 1994$$

Hence, the minimum number of vertices is indeed $1994$.

Comment: @user160738 No. We have 
$$2v-2 = 2\cdot 7 + 20\cdot 100 + \sum_{i=23}^v d_i \geq 2014 + \sum_{i=23}^v 1$$

Comment: Oh sorry, that was stupid